# http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u= content not refreshing with page updates

Tags: facebook, share

I have noticed this numerous times, and have yet to find a fix; when using the share link (http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=MyUrl&t=titleInfo), it pulls in the image, page title, and description from MyUrl just fine. However, it seems to ignore &t, and just uses the page title regardless. That is not the big issue though.

The problem is, if I totally change my page title and opening text, the share link won't update. It seems locked on whatever the page had on it the first time I tested the share link. Is there a way to make it refresh?

In my instance, I was updating some site pages from last years contest edition. Before I got the main page updated, I was working on the FB share link on a different page. I clicked it to test if it worked with the new graphic, and it did, but it of course pulled up the 2012 page content.

Then I went and updated all of the page content to make it for this contest (same URL) and now no matter who tests it, it is still pulling up last year's info (page title and description). It is as if FB has locked that info in and no matter who shares my link, it always pulls up the old text.

I have seen this before with YouTube links. Someone has shared one, I go in later and change the title, and no matter who shares it it never updates because that first initial share text seems permanently locked in FB.

Does anyone know how I can make it refresh, without having to make a whole new URL from last year?

Answer (score 1):

actually facebook gets your page information at the time of posting and save it in their database. so next time it fetches that url and information from their database not from your page.

you may have to share that page again to make new entry in database of the facebook. but old one will remain there.

Answer (score 0):

You can force Facebook to clear their cache by using their debugger. Enter the URL in question  at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug. You need to do this for each page you are working on.

There are also some rules about not changing the info they have if there are more that (50)? likes.